# c - writing float values from csv file into new file & iterating through field

Tags: c, csv, floating-point, field, fread

So basically I have a separate csv file filled with different columns that focuses on icecream toppings and specific sizes/measurements. In my program called convert.c I'm trying to write a program that reads in data from the csv file and writes the data in a new file called toppings.bin with alterations. One column in the csv file contains the weights of different ice cream samples (etc 12.3). What I'm trying to do is take this measurement and write this data to the toppings.bin file as a float. When I attempt to change the data types in my code and run it, the weights in my toppings.bin file all become 0.00000 instead of their appointed values in the csv file. Any help on how to fix this issue would be appreciated.

The weights column is represented as field 3.

convert.c:

```
while(fgets(buf, lineCount, fd){
    char *one = getfield(buf, 1);
    char *two = getfield(buf, 2);
    float *three = getfield(buf, 3);
    if(one && two && three && strcmp(first, "Ice cream") == 0){
      fprintf(ft, "%s %f\n", two, three);
    }
}
```

Comment: Surely, `three` isn't `float` type but `char*`? Format spec `%f` is for `double` (or promoted `float`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char *` cannot be converted to `float` by fprintf.  If three is a string which represents a float you need to convert it using `sscanf`.

ie

```
float weight = 0;
sscanf(three,"%f", &weight);
....
fprintf(ft, "%f", weight);
```

side note answer:

Maybe keep a running total as you're processing?  Or store all weights in a float array and sum them later.